# No sound and microphone detected in Dell G3

Tags: sound, microphone

I have installed Ubuntu in Dell G3. But there is no sound and also no microphone detected. I am not a programmer. So please help me. I have tried all the solutions present on the internet. i.e. pavucontrol, pulseaudio and alsa, everything. but no change

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The command below worked well for the sound problem (Dummy Output). I am not sure if this could work well for you as well. By the way, I still couldn't find any solution for the microphone.

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Also, some people on the Bugzilla says the command below can be used with the new kernel versions.

```
echo "options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/alsa.conf
```